# Android Ghost Layout on Activity Transition

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

I noticed something strange today and i'm not sure the best way to describe it.

I have two activities (A and B). I'm on A and start a new intent for B. I override the pending transition to be a slow slide up. This part is fine.

When B is sliding up I noticed that I can still tap on the screen where B's buttons **would** be and use their actions. (example, there is a close button to close B. When I tap on it's destination area it will close B even though it hasn't completely gone up).

My current solution is to disable all of the buttons until the animation is done. This is working fine, however I'd be interested to know if there is a better (more standard) solution. If anyone can explain (and confirm my suspicions) then that'd be a nice plus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Android is simply animating a transition and not actually moving the views from one physical location to another.